# Node.js 14 ES module import from another folder

Tags: node.js

This is a FYI and a question.

I am using Node.js 14.17.3 (LTS) and wanted to take advantage of using `import` ES syntax to use some files in another project (which need to remain where they are).

So, I made a simple node.js app to test the `import`. I added `"type": "module"` to the `package.json` file in the test app folder.

The (cut down test) file `mixin-modules-definitions.js` to import is:

```
const classModuleDefs = {
   name: 'mydef'
}
export default classModuleDefs
```

Now, if I have that file in the same folder as the `package.json` file of my test app, this works fine:

```
import classModuleDefs from './mixin-modules-definitions.js'

console.log('classModuleDefs=', classModuleDefs)
```

But if I try to import from where the file actually lives like the following, I get the dreaded `SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'` error.

```
import classModuleDefs from '../src/services/mixin-modules-definitions.js'
```

And, if I then add `"type": "module"` to the nearest package.json file relevant to that path, the error goes away and the file is imported correctly.

As it turns out, the app I am importing from is ok with adding `"type": "module"` to its `package.json` file but I could imagine a scenario where it might not be ok.

Is it possible to import a file and have node resolve to use the package.json in my test node app without needing to also change the package.json in the "source" app.

Thanks,
Murray

Comment: No, but if you control the file name, you can give it a `.mjs` extension, and then it will always be loaded as an ES module, regardless of the nearest package file.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately that will break the app that I am importing it from. Good to know, though.

Comment: I think I'm not understanding something about the question. Do you just want to use `import` to import CommonJS modules? Because you can do that. Otherwise, I don't understand why you apparently have the freedom to add a new `mixin-modules-definitions.js` ES module file to a project, but you don't have the freedom to name it `mixin-modules-definitions.mjs`.

Comment: The original `mixin-modules-definitions.js` file is part of a Quasar/Vue app and as such I need to have that file (and many others) as `.js` files using the ES style module as per the example in my question. If I change the file extension to `.mjs` as you suggest the Quasar/Vue app will break. My purpose here is to write a node CLI app that will do some housekeeping for the Quasar app by referencing a number of files there and which involves using the file system in my CLI app (via the node fs module).

Comment: So you are refactoring the modules in `Quasar/Vue` to be ES modules? Or you want to not change them, leave them as CommonJS modules, but be able to `import` them from your CLI project?

Comment: No, I am not doing any refactoring. Maybe I am misunderstanding something. AFAIK the example module in my post is an ES module, not a CommonJS module. As I said, I don't want to touch the original in the Vue app file. I simply want to import it `into` my CLI app, not `from` my CLI app.

Comment: Could you link to the project that you are trying to import files from? Does it use ES modules, but it uses a bundler like webpack, so its package.json file does not contain `"type": "module"` despite its using ES modules? That may be what I was misunderstanding. This makes sense if so.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that is correct. The Quasar/Vue project uses webpack so doesn't need the type:module. I abandoned the idea of a standalone node.js app in favour of doing what I needed to do via the node context in Cypress which all works fine. Thanks again for your help. Case closed. ;-)